# perforce implementation of clearcase like "views"

Tags: perforce

I have read through the documentation on perforce and the "branching strategy" advice as well.
One thing thats left me baffled, is how a simple concern is does not seem to adequtely adressed.
When I am working on a project that touches many parts of our code base , I cannot checkin my code at the end of the day without checking into the trunk. So do I need to branch in this situation? I want to be able to have the ability to have a history of my changes in a long and hard project, so I can go back when I I make a wrong turn..

The problem with branching I see is that I will be creating copies of almost the entire codebase .. Am I missing an obvious solution here?
thanks

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is you are only looking at one extra branch, correct?  Is double the hard drive space of what you currently have a problem?

Answer (score 2):

From the standpoint of the Perforce server, branches aren't actually copies of the files.  Perforce uses a mechanism called "lazy copy" to minimize disc consumption.  From [their website](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/aa_glossary.html), here is the definition of the term:

> A method used by Perforce to make
>   internal copies of files without
>   duplicating file content in the depot.
>   Lazy copies minimize the consumption
>   of disk space by storing references to
>   the original file instead of copies of
>   the file.

Comment: thanks , but I was reffering to space on my desktop. which is limited.

Comment: @Pradyot: I see.  Yes, if you sync to both trunk and branch, you will have two copies of the code.  There's no way around that.

Comment: Yes - important thing to remember about perforce branches is that it effectively stores symbolic links until the files get changed - this means branching has a very low overhead on the server. BTW If your're using perforce then buy and read 'Practical Perforce' - essential stuff

Answer (score 1):

The closest I know of is shelving, in which you can "shelve" your work in progress, saving a copy on the server.  I typically do this to essentially checkpoint my work.  I think this comes closest to addressing your need, where you can save your progress at the end of the day.

See [here](http://filehost.perforce.com/downloads/media/shelving/shelving.html) for a tutorial on shelving in p4v.

Or type `p4 help shelve` for help with the command line.

Comment: I agree, this would be another good option if you don't want two copies of your source tree on your dev machine. (I have to wonder how big such a project is!)

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to working with perforce is to work in a user/feature branch then you can avoid checking into the trunk whilst still pushing your changes into the depot.

When creating a branch, you don't have to branch the entire trunk or source branch - you only need to branch the files you're working on - you can map the rest of the files into your branch via your client spec.

TBH - just buy & read  ['Practical Perforce'](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101855), it has heaps of useful info on how to do this and is very much worth the money if you're using perforce on a daily basis.

Another very useful feature of perforce is 'jobs' - often described only for bug tracking - it's much flexible and allows you to store a changelist history attached to a tag so allowing you to create 'metatags' and attach revisions to it i.e 'NightlyBuild' or 'BreakingChanges or whatever you want.
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate using PDB - Sparse branches. More information here http://www.releng.com/p5layer.html